# batch - add suffix to arguments in one statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know I can reference all the file inputs using `%*`.

Is there a way to change the suffix of all inputs with one command?

I want to do this:

*util.bat:*

```
my_command.exe %*:.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help of command **CALL** output on running `call /?` specifies all possibilities to reference batch file arguments with a modifier.

It is not possible to directly modify the arguments list using other string modifying operations as supported by command **SET** for the string value of an environment variable and explained by help of **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window.

Comment: Mofi is right. The batch arguments list also appears in the output of `FOR /?`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, what you want is a script that rename a bunch of files with a new extension (suffix) given in the parameters.

With this batch you can do that, but only if none of the files has parentheses in their names and the suffix is the **first** parameter.

Here is the code:

**RENAMER.BAT** param1 param2 param3...

- **param1**: new suffix
- **param2, param3, etc**.: the filenames separated with spaces (may need quotes)

**CODE**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Check the existence of the suffix
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Suffix is missing.
    goto:EOF
) else (
    set "suffix=%~1"
)

rem Removes the dot of the suffix
if "%suffix:~0,1%"=="." set "suffix=%suffix:~1%"

shift /1

:Loop
    rem Check if there is still files to rename
    if "%~1"=="" (
        echo Task ended.
        goto:EOF
    ) else (
        set "fileName=%~n1"
    )

    rem Check the existence of the file
    if exist "%~1" (
        ren "%~1" "%fileName%.%suffix%"
    ) else (
        echo File not found: "%~1"
    )

    shift /1
    goto Loop

    goto:EOF
```

Although this solution is not "one command" as you wrote, it can be saved as a batch file to execute like just one command.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Why cant you use two lines of code.

```
Set AllARGs=%*                                                                                                              
Set AllArgsModified=%AllARGs:.txt
```

Comment: That looks like what I need. I'll test it.

Comment: String replacement cannot be done with a command line argument or a `FOR` variable.

Comment: I agree with you guys. I wasnt thinking of the question from the point of view of directly modifying %*.Its actually a big deal especially because some strings/charachters like the % like to disappear and would require doubling.